# How can I deploy and remove components in one step with the ant migration tool?

Tags: deployment, migration-tool, ant, destructivechanges.xml

I am familiar with how to use the destructiveChanges.xml file to remove components from my org.  But it seems like I have to deploy then delete or vice versa.  Is there a way to set up a package so that it will deploy and remove in a single ant command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It actually is possible to do both together. You just need to put metadata component additions and updates into the package.xml, and component removals should be included in destructiveChanges.xml.

Then you can do a single deploy and it will work as expected.

I've put together a working example here:
https://github.com/alan-morey/example-deploy-remove-force-components

Comment: Thanks @Alan Morey.  That actually does work.  Odd though because it does seem to contradict the Salesforce documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Deployment of metadata cannot happen in the same Metadata API transaction as a destructiveChanges deployment.  The following section from the migration tool's documentation is evidence:

> In order to deploy the destructive changes, you must also have a package.xml file that lists no components to deploy, includes the API version, and is in the same directory as destructiveChanges.xml:

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_deploy.htm

You could, however, build an ant target which ran both deployments.

Comment: Thank you. I'll look into doing that.  Also, I think that link is broken.

Comment: If you want examples of more complex sequences you can setup in Ant, feel free to reference the build.xml we use for our project: https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/Cumulus/blob/dev/build.xml     @mark-pond thanks for fixing the formatting.  I'll check for that in the future :)

Comment: @JasonLantz I'm not sure I agree with this. You could have destructiveChanges.xml and package.xml (that lists no components to deploy) in a seperate directory such as 'build'.

i.e.
build/destructivechanges.xml
build/package.xml
src/classes
src/pages
...
src/package.xml

Comment: @cyorkston the reason we don't keep a static destructiveChanges.xml in the repository is because we use feature branches to isolate all development and we deploy all feature branch commits to the same org.  So, say Branch A adds a new trigger and includes a static destructiveChanges.xml that deletes it.  After Branch A builds, Branch B build which does not know that Branch A added a new trigger.  You wind up with stale metadata in the target org (the new trigger) which is not supposed to be there for Branch B.  This is why we dynamically generate destructiveChanges.xml.

Comment: @JasonLantz You certainly can deploy metadata in the same zip file that includes a destructiveChanges.xml. The excerpt from the docs you references is poorly worded. It is referring to a scenario in which you only want to delete metadata. You still must include a package.xml.